# DERIVE LBTETSTCD/LBTEST

Tags: sas, output, sas-macro

The following is my SAS code

```
data lb2;
set lb1_s;
  by subject module visit lbperf;
  if module="LB" then do;
    *case where all LB Modules were not performed;
    if ^(first.lbperf and last.lbperf) and lbperf="0" then do;
      if first.lbperf then output;
    end;
    *case where we have LB Done and Not Done within a visit;
     if lbperf in("0","1") and ^(first.visit and last.visit) then do;
      if lbperf="1" then output;
    end;
    *case where we already have 1 record for Done and Note Done;
    if first.visit and last.visit  then output;

 
  end;
 *else output;


run;
```

I have been asked to keep one record per subject per visit if lbperf="0". If there is at least one lbperf="1" per subject per visit, I delete ones with lbperf="No". My SAS code does it but unfortunately I still have records with both lbperf="1" and "0" in the same visit for one subject

Comment: Your code is not testing for Y or N or No.  Just for 1 or 0.  Also since LBPERF appears to be character you should watch out for values with leading spaces. `"    0"` is different than `"0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOW loop over the visit group to select within the group the rows of the first  LBPERF=0 and the first LBPERF=1. If both occur use coalesceN to choose the row of the "1" case.

Presuming `LBPERF` is $1, and `"0"` means `no` and `"1"` means `yes`.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.visit);
    set have;
    by subject module visit lbperf;

    if module="LB" and lbpref="0" and missing(first0) then first0 = _n_;
    else
    if module="LB" and lbpref="1" and missing(first1) then first1 = _n_;
  end;

  selectN = coalesceN (first1,first0);
  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    if missing(selectN) or _n_ = selectN then 
      output;
  end;
run;
```

An analyst, or policy, might expect a subject/module/visit that has no labs to have only only one record, otherwise there would be one or more records **with** labs.  Real world data collected always contradicts expectations.

Example:

Sort the data with `LBPERF` descending so LB logic is easier.  Every lbperf'd record, or the first non-lbperf record will be output.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by subject module visit descending lbperf;
data want;
  set have;
  by subject module visit descending lbperf;
  if module = 'LB' then do;
    if lbperf or (not lbperf and first.visit) then
      output;
  end;
  else
    output;
run;
```

Comment: Suppose I want to keep all records with lbperf="1" for yes